# Package flashmovie removed from TeX Live?

Tags: packages, texlive, updating

Since my last update of Tex Live (10 days ago), the package `flashmovie` has been removed from TeX Live repository. I'm wondering if it is intentional? Does any one have an idea? It is sort of annoying: after the update this morning, all the users of my team (20 persons) get compilation errors ...

Comment: Look here to see why: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-March/031345.html

Comment: Wow, apparently `movie15` got banned because it only works inside Adobe Reader (which is non-free)! I find that the wrong thing to do.

Comment: At the time it was written, `hyperref` too implemented AdobeReader-only features, I guess.

Comment: @nicolas: If you choose between flashmovie or media9 for a manual install, go for media9. It has a TDS-conform packagefile: [media9.tds.zip](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib/media9.tds.zip).

Answer (score 3):

To understand why `flashmovie` has (currently) been removed from TeX Live, you need to know the policy for inclusion of material. TeX Live is 'Debian free', in the sense that all of the material is available under free-as-in-speech licenses. At the same time, there is a policy of not including code in TeX Live which is itself free but which absolutely requires non-free support material. Sometimes, packages get added to TeX Live which later turn out not to meet the criteria for inclusion, and they are then removed. That does not mean the policy has changed, but reflects the fact that it is not easy to track thousands of separate items. (Note that simply being able to use features from a non-free source is not the issue here, it's requiring non-free support to do anything useful.)

In the case of `flashmovie`, Alexander has linked to the start of the [discussion about this package](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-March/031345.html). The package itself has a free license, but depends on particular PDF features. While there are a lot of free PDF viewers available, feature coverage varies. In the case of 'interactive' material, life is made complicated as there is a difference between the required feature being part of the ISO PDF specification and actually being implemented by a free viewer. Adobe has added many features to PDFs, not all of which are in the ISO and not all of which are implemented by any other viewer.

Now, not being an expert I am not 100% clear on whether the features required by `flashmovie` are (a) part of the ISO PDF standard and (b) available in any free viewer. The latter question seems to be much more complicated than would seem to be the case: there appear to be conflicting opinions!

Comment: If packages use PDF features not in the standard, and so not available for implementation in free PDF readers, then I can understand the exclusion (somewhat), but not otherwise.

Comment: @MartinScharrer As I've tried to make clear, it's not really obvious to me from the discussion I've read whether the required features are part of the ISO or not, and as ISOs cost money I'm reluctant to try to read it to find out. As I understand it, the TL position is that as _practically_ you need Adobe Reader (non-free), then  it's does not really matter that someone could implement the appropriate support. Once/if they _do_, then `flashmovie` goes back in. As I also said, I'm not even clear on whether any of the free readers may already have the appropriate support.

Comment: @Martin: This does not apply here. The PDF features that `media9` and `flashmovie` implement are part of the Adobe ISO 32000 Supplement and thus publicly documented. Otherwise I couldn't have written `media9`.

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn: Makes totally sense! I should have thought about that. In this case I really support these packages as part of TeX Live. (Unfortunate, the comment section is not really the place to discuss this any further.)

Comment: @JosephWright: AFAIK you can get the PDF standard for free. I downloaded it a couple of times. You have to search a little. You can buy it of course, too. I find packages which rely on public available standards should not be excluded. After all, it's a matter of freedom not availability.

Comment: What about cooltooltips.sty? It uses Adobe Javascript API, which is supported by AR only! Sorry for being that harsh but this is a bullshit decision. The problem is the inability of poppler guys to fully support the PDF format. The PDF Reference and now ISO3200 is, were and will be available for free download. To ignore the world behind a horizon set by poor and buggy software is just ... The idea of free software seems to become more and more nonsense and sandpit battle ground for  fundamentalist little kids fighting for their sacred cow!

Comment: @Josef My answer is focussed on the situation as it is, as the Q&A format is not good for discussing whether it is the right decision or not. I am simply reporting what I understand from reading the TL mailing list.

Comment: @Josef, @Martin. `media9` and `flashmovie` seem to be (back) in TeXLive, after all. In case of previous installations in `TEXMFLOCAL`, remove them from there in order to benefit from auto-install/updates via `tlmgr`.